# Healthy unknown partition created in WS2012 R2 storage pools - How to recover?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, raid, windows-server-2012-r2, storage-pool

I'm seting up a file server from a WS 2012 R2 VM hosted in hyper-v. I have a raid 1 array for the file server storage that is implemented by an Adaptec 5805 raid card. This disk was set to offline in the host and passed directly to the storage VM. I then created a simple storage pool from this disk for the commodity to expand storage later. This appeared to work without a hitch, but couple days later the VM stopped working as it reports the passtrough drive "absent". The raid disk was also absent from disk management / diskpart in the hyper-v host. I still could see the drive in device manager Under "drives" but that's it.

The Adaptec bios setup reports the array as "optimal", so is the adaptec management software. I ran a "verify" operation on it and it still reports as in "optimal" state. I took both disk one by one off the raid and they run without problem on a different machine.

I already went through a full Hyper-V reinstallation, thinking a driver went missing/corrupted, but a clean install does not solved the problem. I also tried to uninstall/update the drive/raid controller but nothing brought it back to the surface.

I installed Windows 7 to try a different OS, and the drive is then listed in disk management with a "healthy unknown partition" that can only be deleted. TestDisk identify this partition as "EFI GPT", and I read than win 7 x64 should be able to mount GPT.

Right now, I want to find a solution to recover the data on this drive. How could I proceed? When this is done, I will then focus on what went wrong in my storage pool setup...

If you need more details please ask in comments and I will try to answer promptly.

Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

Healthy unknown means that windows does not recognize the file system format.
This is not good.

You could try some disk rescue products such as :

- [EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard Free](http://www.easeus.com/data-recovery-software/)
- [Paragon Rescue Kit Free Edition](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/rk-free/)

If you cannot repair the disk,
the next step is to try a file-recovery program.
A list and review of such programs can be found in the article
[Best Free Data Recovery and File Un-delete Utility](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-data-recovery-file-undelete-utility.htm).

It would be safer to take an image backup of the disk before trying to repair it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did give a try to both programs mentionned, but none of them got me any further. On the verge of breaking the array and losing all my data, I was more careless and tried all options in TestDisk. To my surprise, it brought back to life my partition as NTFS and I can now access it ! Hurray !! TestDisk is not really intuitive, but it works.

Comment: Test Disk is listed in my above link in third position. I had lately had success on a broken disk with MiniTool Power Data Recovery (first mention in the link), which has a better user interface.

Comment: Why a downvote?

Comment: The downvote didnt came from me.